# Header file iomanip

Tags: header-files

3   20  C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Dev C++\template.cpp  [Error] iomanip.h: No such file or directory
am using the compiler of Dev c++ and while am using manipulator such as setw(),setprecision() and so on I need to use the .
but it gives me the above error

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is just `<iomanip>` not `<iomanip.h>` also if you are not `using namespace std;` you should call the function like this `std::setprecision(5)`

Comment: I have also used the <iomanip> but does not work  @T. Morrell

Comment: can you edit the post to show some of your code please. Preferably where you include the library and where you call the functions

Comment: Now I come over of <iomanip> error now [Error] 'struct std' redeclared as different kind of symbol

Comment: am using class inheritance program is @T.Morrel

Comment: how are you calling the function? can you edit the original post to show your code please.

Comment: sure let me see it

Comment: stdlist.getdata();
            stdlist.getmarks();
            stdlist.display();

Comment: look at the edit I made to my answer I cannot tell from your last comment how you are calling the iomanip functions you referenced in you post.